# autocomplete list in input text box is not coming

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

So i am having problem on `auto completion` feature of jquery. My requirement is to show `Json` data in `auto completion` . Json data is coming from java class in jsp page .This code is working fine but nothing is coming in text box as i type something.

This is my jsp page

```
<%@page import="com.practise.autoComplete.AutoComplete"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSON"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
AutoComplete  autoComplete=new AutoComplete();
JSONObject jsonObject=autoComplete.autoComp();
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<script src="./JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/JS/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
function lookup(inputString) {
    alert("inside lookup");
        if (inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
        var object=<%=jsonObject%>
            var data= JSON.stringify(object);
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $("#inputauto").autocomplete({
                        source: data

                    });
                }

        }
    }
</script>

 <head>


<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <div>

                <br /> Enter  Name to see autocomplete <input
                    type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputauto"
                    onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>

   </html>
```

This is my java file

```
 package com.practise.autoComplete;

    import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

    public class AutoComplete {

        public JSONObject autoComp() {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("1", "peter");
            jsonObject.put("2", "nadia");
            jsonObject.put("3", "jack");
            jsonObject.put("4", "areena");
            return jsonObject;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can check out: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. Its implementation is pretty straight forward, and if you want a "starts with" feature when displaying hits, try: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/select-only-items-that-start-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MichaelSanchez problem is that i want to read  value from key my json is constructing like this {
    "1": "peter",
    "2": "jack",
    "3": "caramon",
    "4": "sebastianblood"
} so i am having problem on this to read . How do i read value from different keys ?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/137/

Comment: You can use a javascript map to hold the key-value pairs, like @vinod_vh's example.